# Como hacer un log en PHP implementando Geolocalización

Tags: php, log

estoy haciendo un log en PHP, ya registro y escribo lo que hace el usuario.

```
    function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
           $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }

    $log = file_put_contents($ruta, $mensaje, FILE_APPEND);
```

Saben como puedo hacer pasa saber de que lugar se están conectando? El País me interesa sobre todo. He probado con geoplugin pero no logro llegar a lo que necesito.

Comment: Realmente no hay método 100% confiable. A veces es más confiable lo que te diga el propio usuario. Imagina que un francés se conecta a tu sitio desde Chile ¿en qué idioma le mostrarías el contenido?. O imagina que tal IP es de un segmento asignado a una compañía brasileña con filial en Chile. Los geoplugins hacer su mejor esfuerzo.

Comment: @Sal, en realidad no está haciendo esa funcionalidad para determinar el idioma, dice que está haciendo un log, me imagino que querrá simplemente guardar ese dato. Pero si, tienes razón en que geoip no es fiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo uso este tipo de Logs para registrar, principalmente algún Bot que quiera meterse donde no deba. A mi Geoplugin me funciona muy bien ya que lo corroboro con el Firewall y la verdad no me da fallos.

```
<?php
    // Defino Zona horaria a usar
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

    // Quito las IPs que no quiero que se incluyan en el Log
    $myIPs = ['285.313.269.299', '275.213.69.99'];

    // Extraigo la IP del cliente con esta función
    function getIpAddress() {
        $heads = ['HTTP_CLIENT_IP','HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_X_FORWARDED','HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP','HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR','HTTP_FORWARDED','REMOTE_ADDR'];
        foreach($heads as $head){
            if(array_key_exists($head, $_SERVER)){
                foreach(array_map('trim',explode(',',$_SERVER[$head])) as $ip){
                    if ( filter_var( $ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE ) !== false ) {
                        return $ip;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 'UNKNOWN';
    }
    $ip = getIpAddress();

    // Aca hago el filtro de mis IPs a no tomar en cuenta
    if (!in_array($ip, $myIPs)) {
        // Obtengo la Geolocation de la IP
        function getGeolocation() {
            $ip = getIpAddress();
            $data = unserialize(@file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$ip));
            return $data;
        }
        $location = getGeolocation();

        // Acá guardo en variables la información a escribir en el Log
        /* De la Global $_SERVER se coge toda la información
        que queramos, puedes ver todo lo que $_SERVER tiene con lo siguiente

        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($_SERVER);
        echo "</pre>";

        */
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date = $date->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
        $country = $location['geoplugin_countryName']; // Pais
        $city = $location['geoplugin_city']; // Ciudad
        $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; // POST o GET
        $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Que ruta visitan

        // Escribo en mi OCHOA_log.txt
        $file = 'OCHOA_log.txt';
        $log = $date.' - '.$ip.' - '.$country.' - '.$city.' - '.$method.' - '.$request.' - '.' * ';

        if (is_writable($file)) {
            $file = fopen($file, "a");
            fwrite($file, $log.PHP_EOL);
            fclose($file);
        }
    }

    /* Si por alguna razón (más que todo didactica) quieres ver ese log 
    en el navegador (pocos registros) puedes hacerlo así */
    
    // Lees tu log y buscas el separador de cada dato para crear un array
    // yo le puse como separarador un espacio un guion medio y otro espacio
    $lines = file('log.txt');

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $logs[] = explode(" - ", $line);
    }

?>
```

Y el HTML

```html
<!-- Haces una tabla sencilla  -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OCHOA Log</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h3 class="text-center mb-3 mt-3">IPs LOG</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
                    <th scope="col">IP</th>
                    <th scope="col">País</th>
                    <th scope="col">Ciudad</th>
                    <th scope="col">Method</th>
                    <th scope="col">URL</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    foreach ($logs as $log) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        <?php echo $log[0]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        <?php echo $log[1]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        <?php echo $log[2]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        <?php echo $log[3]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        <?php echo $log[4]; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="align-middle">
                        <?php echo $log[5]; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El resultado es este

[image: Log]

Como ya te dijeron, Geoplugin no es del 100% "confiable" pues puede que alguien cerca de ti use VPNs o que no registre (como en mi ejemplo) algunas ciudades, pero por lo demás nunca he visto una diferencia en el País de origen de una petición.

Yo uso este Log en los **404** de algunos sitios y me sirve para monitorizar y controlar trafico malicioso, luego en mi Firewall lo cotejo y lo bloqueo y como te repito estoy muy contento con su funcionamiento.

Comment: Lo pruebo y te comento.

Answer (score 0):

En la versión inglesa de stackoverflow, hay una respuesta a esta misma pregunta que resuelve tus dudas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553160/getting-visitors-country-from-their-ip

Pego aquí el código tal cual y paso a explicar un poco lo que hace:

```
<?php

function ip_info($ip = NULL, $purpose = "location", $deep_detect = TRUE) {
    $output = NULL;
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) === FALSE) {
        $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        if ($deep_detect) {
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (filter_var(@$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
    }
    $purpose    = str_replace(array("name", "\n", "\t", " ", "-", "_"), NULL, strtolower(trim($purpose)));
    $support    = array("country", "countrycode", "state", "region", "city", "location", "address");
    $continents = array(
        "AF" => "Africa",
        "AN" => "Antarctica",
        "AS" => "Asia",
        "EU" => "Europe",
        "OC" => "Australia (Oceania)",
        "NA" => "North America",
        "SA" => "South America"
    );
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && in_array($purpose, $support)) {
        $ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));
        if (@strlen(trim($ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode)) == 2) {
            switch ($purpose) {
                case "location":
                    $output = array(
                        "city"           => @$ipdat->geoplugin_city,
                        "state"          => @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName,
                        "country"        => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName,
                        "country_code"   => @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode,
                        "continent"      => @$continents[strtoupper($ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode)],
                        "continent_code" => @$ipdat->geoplugin_continentCode
                    );
                    break;
                case "address":
                    $address = array($ipdat->geoplugin_countryName);
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_regionName) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    if (@strlen($ipdat->geoplugin_city) >= 1)
                        $address[] = $ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    $output = implode(", ", array_reverse($address));
                    break;
                case "city":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_city;
                    break;
                case "state":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "region":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_regionName;
                    break;
                case "country":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryName;
                    break;
                case "countrycode":
                    $output = @$ipdat->geoplugin_countryCode;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $output;
}

?>
```

¿Cómo se usa?

*Ejemplo 1: Muestra los datos de la IP de un visitante:*

```
<?php

echo ip_info("Visitor", "Country"); // India
echo ip_info("Visitor", "Country Code"); // IN
echo ip_info("Visitor", "State"); // Andhra Pradesh
echo ip_info("Visitor", "City"); // Proddatur
echo ip_info("Visitor", "Address"); // Proddatur, Andhra Pradesh, India

print_r(ip_info("Visitor", "Location")); // Array ( [city] => Proddatur [state] => Andhra Pradesh [country] => India [country_code] => IN [continent] => Asia [continent_code] => AS )

?>
```

*Ejemplo 2: Muestra los datos de una IP concreta:*

```
<?php

echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Country"); // United States
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Country Code"); // US
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "State"); // California
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "City"); // Menlo Park
echo ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Address"); // Menlo Park, California, United States

print_r(ip_info("173.252.110.27", "Location")); // Array ( [city] => Menlo Park [state] => California [country] => United States [country_code] => US [continent] => North America [continent_code] => NA )

?>
```

Lo que hace la función es que dada una IP (o la del visitante por defecto), se le pasa un parámetro a consultar ($purpose) que por defecto es "location" y lanza una consulta contra http://www.geoplugin.net/ para obtener los datos. Luego retorna esos datos según lo que se ha especificado.

Comment: Gracias, lo pruebo y te digo como me va. Algo así había visto pero lo lo había podido implementar, lo voy a ver más detenidamente.